# Hibernate Mapping Exception [Tried previous solutions]

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I am trying to run a maven based Hibernate Hello World Project. I have done every step right but it is giving Hibernate Mapping Exception: Unknown Entity. I have already declared mapping of my Entity class in Hibernate.cfg.xml.

Here is my configuration file code.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>


    <!-- Database connection settings -->

    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
    </property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">root</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup
         if table isn't present hibernate will create the table -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <mapping class="com.openlibrary.model.Book"/>


</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here is Session Factory code

```
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

    if (sessionFactory == null) {

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

    }
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

And my model class
    package com.openlibrary.model;

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    int bookID;
    String bookName;

    public int getBookID() {
        return bookID;
    }

    public void setBookID(int bookID) {
        this.bookID = bookID;
    }

    public String getBookName() {
        return bookName;
    }

    public void setBookName(String bookName) {
        this.bookName = bookName;
    }
}
```

And here is the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister: com.openlibrary.model.Book
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.locateEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:787)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.locateEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:2637)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2500(SessionImpl.java:164)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2575)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2562)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.byId(SessionImpl.java:1044)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:955)
at com.openlibrary.dao.BookDAO.getBookById(BookDAO.java:43)
at com.openlibrary.test.Testing.main(Testing.java:22)
```

I know such question has been asked before But I am unable to understand why hibernate throws exception when mapping is already done. I did it last time almost a year back. It was working the same way. Need help here.

Now there is a little twist in scenario. I bypassed the exception by changing my maven dependency of hibernate-core. I was getting the exception with this dependency. It was latest on maven website.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.CR2</version>
 </dependency>
```

I changed the version to 4.3.7.Final. Then there was no exception. I dont know why it is throwing exception. Maybe someone can explain. I will really appreciate that.

Comment: Should the file be named hibernate.cfg.xml (case sensitive, h instead of H)? Are you sure you really used your config file (may be you have another config file in your class path? Or have you packaged your entity class to the application?

Comment: Can you please post the exception that you're getting?

Comment: @diufanman sorry I just typed wrong in the question. It is actually hibernate.cfg.xml and the same in my project. And yeah I am sure about thew configuration file and I have my packaged the entity class rightly.

Comment: @Rdx I am adding the exception in question.
Now there is a little twist in scenario. I bypassed the exception by changing my maven dependency of hibernate-core. I was getting the exception with this dependency. hibernate-core and version 5.0.0.CR2. It was latest on maven website. [The exact code is added in the question at end] But when I changed the version to 4.3.7.Final. Then there was no exception. I dont know why it is throwing exception. Maybe you can explain. I will appreciate that. :)

Answer (score 2):

First implement the Serializable interface in your entity class,

```
public class Book implements Serializable{
}
```

Secondly Don't use Configuration with StandardServiceRegistryBuilder, Configuration is considered deprecated,
but instead make the bootstrapping as mentioned in the hibernate 5 documentation, for reference go tobelow link,

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userGuide/en-US/html_single/#bootstrap-native-sessionfactory

or you can modify your code as below to give a try i hope it will work

```
if (sessionFactory == null) {

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        configuration.addClass( Book.class ).addResource( "com/openlibrary/model/Book.hbm.xml" );
        serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry.build());

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

your book not implemented Serializable.
try with this.

```
public class Book implements Serializable{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Configuration with StandardServiceRegistryBuilder, Configuration is considered deprecated, but instead make the bootstrapping as mentioned in the hibernate 5 documentation, I had the same problem and this fixed it.

```
StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
.configure( "org/hibernate/example/MyCfg.xml" )
.build();

Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources( standardRegistry )
.addAnnotatedClass( MyEntity.class )
.addAnnotatedClassName( "org.hibernate.example.Customer" )
.addResource( "org/hibernate/example/Order.hbm.xml" )
.addResource( "org/hibernate/example/Product.orm.xml" )
.getMetadataBuilder()
.applyImplicitNamingStrategy( ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl.INSTANCE )
.build();

SessionFactory sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder()
.applyBeanManager( getBeanManagerFromSomewhere() )
.build();
```

for further details , check the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userGuide/en-US/html_single/#bootstrap-native-sessionfactory)

Answer (score 0):

I believe, with the latest versions of hibernate they have removed support for the `<mapping>` tag in the configuration file. Instead you can use `addAnnotatedClass(<Your domain class>)` method defined in the Configuration class. i.e., configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Book.class); in this case.

-Madhu.

Answer (score 0):

-Your Book Model class is not implemented Serializable interface.

-Try with below code.

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

    @Entity
    public class Book implements Serializable {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        int bookID;
        String bookName;

        public int getBookID() {
            return bookID;
        }

        public void setBookID(int bookID) {
            this.bookID = bookID;
        }

        public String getBookName() {
            return bookName;
        }

        public void setBookName(String bookName) {
            this.bookName = bookName;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you should add, but doesn't have impact:

```
  public class Book implements Serializable{
   }
```

But when I changed the version to 4.3.7.Final. Then there was no exception.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
   </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the fact that at some point hibernate started using the annotations from jakarta.persistence.* as opposed to java.persistence.*